# c# - cpu friendly single thread console app that do something every minute

Tags: c#, timer, console-application, infinite-loop, keep-alive

I wrote a c# console application, which should do a task (e.g calling a method) once a minute. The Basic structure is looking like following

```
while(true)
{
Thread.Sleep(10000)
// Call methodA
}
```

Sadly that while infinity loop produces a high cpu usage. I've read that Threads are more cost-efficient than infinite while loops. So i wrote that piece of code into my program.cs:

```
timer.Elapsed += New ElapsedEventHandler(methodA);
timer.Intervall = 10000;
timer.Enabled = True;
```

After that piece of code my app is shutting down. Even the thread wont be executed anymore and methodA will never be called. So from my point of view, i need to embed that piece of code with a while loop again. I think there are many better ways, e.g. via WaitHandler. But its unclear to me, how i can keep my app alive. May someone can give me a code Example

Comment: CPU use should be exactly 0 during the Thread.Sleep interval, is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: @AlexK. the process had still a cpu usage of 46%. But i tried it again now and it worked out! CPU Usage is at 0%. I feel a bit ashamed that I made an extra question for this, but at least it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason your application closes when you try to use the event might be that it reaches the end of the main method, causing the application to close.

One fairly simple change would be to make your console app use an [async main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) method. That way you should be able to replace the Thread.Sleep with `await Task.Delay(...)`. This will use a timer behind the scene, while still preventing it from closing until it is done.

There might not be any real advantage however for a console application. `Task.Sleep` should sleep the current thread, and while sleeping it will not use any CPU time. While `await Task.Delay` will free the thread to do other things, it will not help if there are no other things to do.